# Ubuntu 18.04 clock is faster by 2min

Tags: 18.04, time

Automatic sync is on for both time-zone (Automatic Time Zone) and time (Automatic Date & Time) in the settings pane.

I also have tried this:

```
sudo timedatectl set-ntp off
sudo timedatectl set-ntp on
```

But it does not sync my desktop clock. Apart from manually setting the minutes, what can I do?

Comment: 1. Faster that what clock? Are you sure that the other clock is correct? 2. Is your computer connected to the internet?

Comment: Yes I checked a few clocks (my phone, internet, other computers). And it is connected to internet.

Comment: It *should* sync automatically to the correct time via the internet. 1. Have you modified anything related to the date and time settings? 2. Have you found the 'Date & Time' settings window in your 18.04 LTS? Click at the top right corner - the tools button - (Settings) Details - Date & Time

Comment: Right, I'd expect it sync automactially. And yes I checked the Date & Time pane. Both settings for auto-sync are enabled. Very annoying!!

Comment: What happens if you boot from a live USB drive with Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS in the same computer? Will it display the correct time or will the live session also have a 2 minute off-set?

Comment: @sudodus, faster than all other computers which have the same settings. I have 2 PCs with Ubuntu 16 and one two with Ubuntu 18.04 - everything is correct. Today I'm setup a PC for my mother and suddenly the time was 3 minutes faster than the others PCs...

Answer (score 3):

I just solved the very same problem by **switching to `ntpd`**, as it is suggested in the DO's article [How To Set Up Time Synchronization on Ubuntu 18.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-time-synchronization-on-ubuntu-18-04). The commands are:

```bsh
sudo timedatectl set-ntp no  # 1. Turn off 'timesyncd' before installing 'ntpd'
timedatectl                  # 2. Verify that 'timesyncd' is of
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ntp         # 3. Install 'ntp' package
```

`ntpd` will be started automatically after install. You can query ntpd for status information to verify that everything is working:

```bsh
ntpq -p
```

Comment: ntp was already installed in my system, but wasn't running.
So I started it by: `systemctl start ntp.service` and now my 2min offset is gone. Thank you.