# Ubuntu 22.04 time behind 1 minute

Tags: 22.04, ntp

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 on AWS and noticed the time was behind by one minute. The only thing I changed was the timezone using:

`sudo timedatectl set-timezone "America/Chicago"`

I also tried switching to ntpd using this suggestion:
[Ubuntu 18.04 clock is faster by 2min](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1081185/ubuntu-18-04-clock-is-faster-by-2min)

Any ideas?

Comment: Is `ntpd` running?

Comment: Yes, @Jos it shows to be running.